# Boolean always returning as true?

Tags: java, class

So I'm working with 3 class files. A piece of my code from file 1 is calling some code from file 2 that checks to see if a product database, file3, is full. I'm expecting the databaseFull method to return a false but it seems to only return true even if there is only a single item in the database.
Can I please get some assistance as to why this is happening?
edit: upon request i have pasted all of my code

File 1 code:

```
public class StarberksInterface
{
Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    StarberksInterface intFace = new StarberksInterface();
    intFace.run();
}

private void run() 
{
    int option, demandRate, choice;
    double setupCost, unitCost, inventoryCost, sellPrice;
    String productName, newProductName, deleteName;
    Store store = new Store();

    do {
        System.out.println("(1) Input data for one product\n(2) Show data from one product\n(3) Show product replenishment strategy\n(4) Exit");
        option = console.nextInt();
        switch(option)
        {
            case 1: 
                System.out.println("Enter product name (3 to 10 characters): ");
                productName = console.next().toLowerCase();

                while(productName.length()>10 || productName.length()<3 ){
                    System.out.println("Product name length is not valid. Try again.");
                    productName = console.next().toLowerCase();
                }

                if (store.databaseFull()){
                    System.out.println("Database is full:\n(1) Delete a product\n(2) Menu");
                    choice = console.nextInt();
                    if (choice == 1){
                        System.out.println("Enter name of product to delete: ");
                        deleteName = console.next().toLowerCase();
                        store.deleteProduct(deleteName);
                        System.out.println("Product deleted.");
                        break;
                    }
                    else{
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (store.productExists(productName)){
                    System.out.println("Product already exists:\n(1) Change the product name\n(2) Change product data\n(3) Menu"); 
                    choice = console.nextInt();
                    if (choice == 1){
                        System.out.println("Enter new product name: ");
                        newProductName = console.next().toLowerCase();
                        while(newProductName.length()>10 || newProductName.length()<3 ){
                            System.out.println("Product name length is not valid. Try again.");
                            newProductName = console.next().toLowerCase();
                        }
                        store.changeName(productName, newProductName);

                    }else if (choice == 2){
                        System.out.println("Enter new demand rate: ");
                        demandRate = console.nextInt();
                        demandRate = checkInput(demandRate);

                        System.out.println("Enter new setup cost: ");
                        setupCost = console.nextDouble();
                        setupCost = checkInput(setupCost);

                        System.out.println("Enter new unit cost: ");
                        unitCost = console.nextDouble();
                        unitCost = checkInput(unitCost);

                        System.out.println("Enter new inventory cost: ");
                        inventoryCost = console.nextDouble();
                        inventoryCost = checkInput(inventoryCost);

                        System.out.println("Enter new sell price: ");
                        sellPrice = console.nextDouble();
                        sellPrice = checkInput(sellPrice);

                        System.out.println("Data changed.");

                        store.changeData(productName, demandRate, setupCost, unitCost, inventoryCost, sellPrice);                     
                    } 
                    else{
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else{
                    // user inputs
                    System.out.println("Enter demand rate: ");
                    demandRate = console.nextInt();
                    demandRate = checkInput(demandRate);

                    System.out.println("Enter setup cost: ");
                    setupCost = console.nextDouble();
                    setupCost = checkInput(setupCost);

                    System.out.println("Enter unit cost: ");
                    unitCost = console.nextDouble();
                    unitCost = checkInput(unitCost);

                    System.out.println("Enter inventory cost: ");
                    inventoryCost = console.nextDouble();
                    inventoryCost = checkInput(inventoryCost);

                    System.out.println("Enter sell price: ");
                    sellPrice = console.nextDouble();
                    sellPrice = checkInput(sellPrice);

                    store.addProduct(productName, demandRate, setupCost, unitCost, inventoryCost, sellPrice);
                }
                break;

            case 2:
                System.out.println("Enter product name (3 to 10 characters): ");
                productName = console.next().toLowerCase();

                while(productName.length()>10 || productName.length()<3 ){
                    System.out.println("Product name length is not valid. Try again.");
                    productName = console.next().toLowerCase();
                }

                while (!store.productExists(productName)){
                    System.out.println("This product does not exist, try again.");
                    productName = console.next().toLowerCase();

                    while(productName.length()>10 || productName.length()<3 ){
                        System.out.println("Product name length is not valid. Try again.");
                        productName = console.next().toLowerCase();
                    }
                }

                //at this point, the product entered will exist in the store, so you will be able to show the product details
                showData(store.getProduct(productName));

                break;

            /**case 3: System.out.println
             * 
             * 
             * 
                break;**/

            case 4: break;

            default: System.out.println("invalid option");
        }
    }
    while(option!=4);
}

public void option1(){ 

}

public void option2(){

}

public void option3(){

}

public void option4(){

}

// This function checks integer inputs for negative numbers and returns a message and/or the input.
public int checkInput(int input){

    while(input < 0){
        System.out.println("Cannot input negative number. Try again.");
        input = console.nextInt();
    }

    return input;
}

// This function checks double inputs for negative numbers and returns a message and/or the input.
public double checkInput(double input){

    while(input < 0){
        System.out.println("Cannot input negative number. Try again.");
        input = console.nextDouble();
    }

    return input;
}

private static void showData(Product product)
{
  System.out.println("Name = "+product.getProductName());
  System.out.println("Demand rate = "+product.getDemandRate());
  System.out.println("Setup cost = "+product.getSetupCost());
  System.out.println("Unit cost = "+product.getUnitCost());
  System.out.println("Inventory cost = "+product.getInventoryCost());
  System.out.println("Sell price = "+product.getSellPrice());
}
```

}

File 2 code:

```
public class Store
{
private Product product1;
private Product product2;
private Product product3;

public Store(){
    product1 = null;
    product2 = null;
    product3 = null;
}

public void addProduct(String name, int demand, double setup, double unit, double inventory, double sell ){
    if(product1 == null){
        product1 = new Product();
        product1.setProductName(name);
        product1.setDemandRate(demand);
        product1.setSetupCost(setup);
        product1.setUnitCost(unit);
        product1.setInventoryCost(inventory);
        product1.setSellPrice(sell);
    }

    if(product2 == null){
        product2 = new Product();
        product2.setProductName(name);
        product2.setDemandRate(demand);
        product2.setSetupCost(setup);
        product2.setUnitCost(unit);
        product2.setInventoryCost(inventory);
        product2.setSellPrice(sell);
    }

    if(product3 == null){
        product3 = new Product();
        product3.setProductName(name);
        product3.setDemandRate(demand);
        product3.setSetupCost(setup);
        product3.setUnitCost(unit);
        product3.setInventoryCost(inventory);
        product3.setSellPrice(sell);
    }
}

public void changeName(String oldName, String newName){
    if(product1 != null){
        if(product1.getProductName().equals(oldName))
            product1.setProductName(newName);
    }

    if(product2 != null){
        if(product2.getProductName().equals(oldName))
            product2.setProductName(newName);
    }

    if(product3 != null){
        if(product3.getProductName().equals(oldName))
            product3.setProductName(newName);
    }  
}

public void changeData(String name, int demand, double setup, double unit, double inventory, double sell ){
    if(product1 != null){
        if(product1.getProductName().equals(name))
            product1.setDemandRate(demand);
            product1.setSetupCost(setup);
            product1.setUnitCost(unit);
            product1.setInventoryCost(inventory);
            product1.setSellPrice(sell);
    }

    if(product2 != null){
        if(product2.getProductName().equals(name))
            product2.setDemandRate(demand);
            product2.setSetupCost(setup);
            product2.setUnitCost(unit);
            product2.setInventoryCost(inventory);
            product2.setSellPrice(sell);
    }

    if(product3 != null){
        if(product3.getProductName().equals(name))
            product3.setDemandRate(demand);
            product3.setSetupCost(setup);
            product3.setUnitCost(unit);
            product3.setInventoryCost(inventory);
            product3.setSellPrice(sell);
    }  
}

public boolean productExists(String name){
    if (product1 != null){
        if (name.equals(product1.getProductName()))
            return true;
    }

    if (product2 != null){
        if (name.equals(product2.getProductName()))
            return true;
    }

    if (product3 != null){
        if (name.equals(product3.getProductName()))
            return true;
    }

    return false; 
}

public Product getProduct(String name){
    if (product1 != null){
        if (name.equals(product1.getProductName()))
            return product1;
    }

    if (product2 != null){
        if (name.equals(product2.getProductName()))
            return product2;
    }

    if (product3 != null){
        if (name.equals(product3.getProductName()))
            return product3;
    }

    return null; 
}

public boolean databaseFull(){
    return (product1 != null && product2 != null && product3 != null);      
}

public void deleteProduct(String name){
    if (name.equals(product1.getProductName())){
        product1 = null;
    }

    if (name.equals(product2.getProductName())){
        product2 = null;
    } 

    if (name.equals(product3.getProductName()))
        product3 = null;
}
```

}

File 3 code:

```
public class Product
{
private String name;
private int demand;
private double setup, unit, inventory, sell;

public Product()
{
  name = "NO NAME";
  demand = 0;
  setup = 0;
  unit = 0;
  inventory = 0;
  sell = 0;
}

public void setProductName(String productName)
{
    name = productName;
}

public void setDemandRate(int demandRate)
{
    demand = demandRate;
}

public void setSetupCost(Double setupCost)
{
    setup = setupCost;
}

public void setUnitCost(Double unitCost)
{
    unit = unitCost;
}

public void setInventoryCost(Double inventoryCost)
{
    inventory = inventoryCost;
}

public void setSellPrice(Double sellPrice)
{
    sell = sellPrice;
}

public String getProductName()
{
  return name;
}

public int getDemandRate()
{
  return demand;
}

public double getSetupCost()
{
  return setup;
}

public double getUnitCost()
{
  return unit;
}

public double getInventoryCost()
{
  return inventory;
}

public double getSellPrice()
{
  return sell;
}
```

}

Comment: Debugging might help you out. We have no idea about your DB side.

Comment: What are product1-2-3 ?? Post the whole class.

Comment: your Store class won't compile, so I very much doubt that method returns true

Comment: Nothing obviously wrong with your code, so the bug is probably somewhere else, i.e. the part where you populate `product1`, `product2`, `product3`

Comment: Thanks for the replies. As request I edited my original post and included the entirety of my code for all 3 files.

Comment: You should really cut back the amount of code to the bare minimum to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time you pass into the `addProduct()` method your are setting product1, product2 and product3 with `new Product()`.

```
public void addProduct(String name, int demand, double setup, double unit, double inventory, double sell ){
    if(product1 == null){
        product1 = new Product();
        //...
    }

    if(product2 == null){
        product2 = new Product();
        //..
    }

    if(product3 == null){
        product3 = new Product();
        //..
    }
}
```

So later because all those 3 attributes are referencing valid **Product** instances :

`product1 != null` returns `true`

`product2 != null` returns `true`

`product3 != null` returns `true`

Then

`(product1 != null && product2 != null && product3 != null)` will return **true** because you always create 3 products in your store. ( BTW you are creating 3 times the same )

Try this :

```
public void addProduct(String name, int demand, double setup, double unit, double inventory, double sell ){
    if(product1 == null){
        product1 = new Product();
        //...
    }else if(product2 == null){
        product2 = new Product();
      //...
    }else if(product3 == null){
        product3 = new Product();
      //...
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about what you're saying. You mean that all 3 products have been initialized and so they are no longer null?      
Would changing my addProduct's if statements to if else's fix this problem?      
Also, does this mean all 3 of them are taking on the values of the user's input?